# Do we have established terms yet for persons either addicted or averse to social media?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, social-media

Terms for addicts are easily enough improvised by adding *-oholic* to the name for a specific social media platform, e.g. “Twitter-oholic,” but is there something more generic, & less unwieldy & artificial than “social-media-oholic”?

Terms for abstainers seem even harder to come by.

The very term “social media” seems to me to provoke the question: “How could any communications medium *not* be social?”

The [M-W definition for “social media”](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/social%20media) would appear applicable to EL&U itself, so although I am a total abstainer from Facebook & Twitter & even smart phones, one of the addict terms may apply to me, though the recipe above would generate a pretty unwieldy result.

Comment: Some might suggest that only thing the *-oholic* suffix isn't unwieldy and artificial after, is *alc*.

Comment: [Related](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4732/word-for-disrespecting-eldest-half-sister-by-referring-to-her-husband-as-girly-g#comment16076_4732).

Answer (score 3):

A fan of technology might be called a *technophile*.

The opposite would be called a *technophobe*.

For the latter, the term *Luddite* also comes to mind.

Comment: These terms imply an addiction or aversion much broader than just to social media, even granting the recent narrowing of the usage of *technology* to mean just *digital electronics* ( excluding stone axes, the alphabet, etc.).

Comment: @BrianDonovan I don't disagree. On the other hand, the terms you're looking for are probably too new to really be in use yet. You might have to settle for something a little broader, or make up your own word.

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364 for the use–mention distinction, please use an italic face not a bold one. It makes the page look too heavy otherwise, and furthermore runs counter to typographic convention both on this site and in scholarly works.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a person  averse to social media can be called [*social media (networking) phobic*](http://cyhealthcommunications.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/kt-therapy-for-the-social-media-phobic-pal12/) while  its opposite can be defined as [*social media (networking) addicted*](http://m.wikihow.com/Defeat-a-Social-Networking-Addiction).

Answer (score 0):

Consider: *[Off-the-grid.](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/off+the+grid)*

Notably this part of the second definition:

> not traceable through any means of commerce or communication that could be linked to one's identity.

This phrase has historically referred to people who lived without ties to municipal utilities, but it's growing in usage to refer to those who abstain from social media, especially in reference to when a person almost invariably cannot be reached if they aren't on social media.

Comment: edit in the definition of your answer and how the sense fits ... you may get votes

Comment: I don't think it fits well. Similarly, *not drinking* doesn't mean *abstainer.*